# Problemas com digitação teclado virtual Firemonkey Android

Tags: android, teclado, firemonkey, delphi-10

Tenho um aplicativo rodando em aparelhos com Android (5, 6 e 7) e apresenta um problema na digitação das palavras - diferente do autocompletar - pois ele simplesmente repete letras aleatoriamente. Esse mesmo problema já ocorria no Delphi XE8. Cheguei a tentar algumas sugestões para mudar o teclado (KeyboardType = Alphabet), mas sem sucesso. Alguma dica? Grato!

Comment: Bem Vindo! Por favor, sugerimos que realize um [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo site e veja Como criar um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Assim, facilita a comunidade a te ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema que você usando o `Delphi XE7`, passei por vários testes e percebi que nenhum dos `KeyBoardType` não resolvia, o Alphabet usa as sugestões do teclado virtual do Android. Tanto no teclado do celular quanto o do GBoard(Teclado do google) não funcionava.

Testei com o `KeyBoardType = Alphabet` mas com a opção `Password` checada, se você observar ele não usa sugestões do teclado e não estava mais repetindo as letras que por sinal para mim iria resolver, mas tem um porém, com a opção `Password` checada ele só aparece símbolos e mesmo com o botão para ter a possibilidade de visualizar o que está sendo digitado não adiantava.

Então tive que fazer uma pequena alteração. Pesquisa pela unit `FMX.Platform.Android` responsável pelos controles de KeyBoard do Android entre outras coisas. Faz uma cópia dessa unit e cole na pasta do seu projeto e declare ela no uses do projeto, para começar a pegar as alterações dessa unit.

Com a unit aberta pesquisa pela função `EnterControl` e `HandleVK` onde existir a seguinte chamada

> FTextView.setIsPassword(Password)

altere para

> FTextView.setIsPassword(True)

ele vai ativar a opção do Password sem as sugestões do teclado e com a possibilidade de visualizar o que estão sendo digitado sem ter um botão para fazer isso. Para mim resolveu.

Comment: Excelente solução @JeffersonRudolf. Resolveu o problema de forma eficiente. Grato pela ajuda!

Comment: @dvdmengarda Obrigado, se a resposta foi de grande ajuda, podes marcar a resposta. Abraços!

Comment: Exelente dica! era o que eu estava esperando

Answer (score -2):

Eu tirei todos os comandos dos eventos do edit que funcionam em tempo de
digitação: change e tracking e coloquei o teclado alphabet e resolveu.
O usuário digita e clica na lupinha que localiza ao invez de ir localizando enquanto
digita. Pra mim resolveu pois quando atualiza o FMX pedia outros FMX utilizo delphi seatle.